# Fuzzy find within file in Vim

Tags: vim

I love using the Command-T plugin in Vim to do fuzzy searches for filenames. I like it so much that I've started to want to do the same fuzzy searches for arbitrary strings within an open buffer.

For example, if I'm editing a CSS file that contains a selector like `#support-main .question .answer-rating`, I can currently type `/support-main .question` to find that line.

I'd like to be able to invoke a fuzzy finder and simply type something like `supmaique` to find that same line (among others). I know I can type `/sup.*mai.*que` for the same effect but typing the `.*`'s breaks my concentration.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is "line" extension in the latest Ctrl-P plugin for vim ([ctrlp](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim)) which can do fuzzy line search. You need to enable the extension manually. Here is my config in `.vimrc`:

```
let g:ctrlp_map = '<c-p>'
let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlPLastMode'
let g:ctrlp_extensions = ['buffertag', 'tag', 'line', 'dir']
```

After that you press `Ctrl-p` to bring menu, then press `Ctrl-f` several times until the line mode is on. Type your fuzzy string now:

[image]

**UPDATE 27 Feb 2014**

An alternative solution that I'm currently using myself would be to use [unite](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim). In order to do fuzzy line search you need to slightly tune unite:

```
call unite#filters#matcher_default#use(['matcher_fuzzy'])
call unite#filters#sorter_default#use(['sorter_rank'])
call unite#custom#source('file,file/new,buffer,file_rec,line', 'matchers', 'matcher_fuzzy')
nnoremap <C-k> :<C-u>Unite -buffer-name=search -start-insert line<cr>
```

Now press `Ctrl-k` and type:

[image]

By the way, unite can also do fuzzy file search by name.

**UPDATE 03 Aug 2016**

Another way to do line search is to use [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) along with accompanying [vim plugin](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim). See the installation instructions here: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim#installation

After you have installed both fzf and fzf.vim, you can use `:BLines` to search lines in the current buffer:

[image: Sample output]

You may have noticed it's not exactly fuzzy search meaning that I need to use spaces. This may not work you.

Comment: Added unite as an alternative solution.

Comment: Added fzf as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you want, but with `set incsearch` your pattern is matched as you type. It's not really fuzzy matching but the feeling is sort of similar.

Comment: Ah, yes. `incsearch` is great, but not what I'm looking for.